# Picking list in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to create a picking list template for a logistic process in a warehouse. Following is the planned structure:

- row1: header
- scanned data: part number (column A), quantity (column B), location (column C)
- timestamp of scanning automatically entered in column D when quantity scanned
- all the cells are protected except of scanned data
- one picking list contains max. 10 rows, then
  save the file with timestamp (in xls, txt, csv etc. format): picking_list_ddmmyy_hhmm.ext,
  print 3 copies on default printer,
  and re-open the blank sheet for another scanning.
- if picking list is shorter than 10 rows, option need to print it manually. when Print button pressed, then
  save the file with timestamp (in xls, txt, csv etc. format): picking_list_ddmmyy_hhmm.ext,
  print 3 copies on default printer,
  and re-open the blank sheet for scanning.

I am here with the project (being a enthusiastic beginner I used different google findings, but I am stuck):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Target.Column = 3 And Target.Count = 1 And Target(1).Value <> "" Then 
      Range("A" & Target.Row + 1).Select
      Dim x As Integer
      For x = 2 To 1000
         If Cells(x, 3).Value <> "" And Cells(x, 4).Value = "" Then
            Cells(x, 4).Value = Date & " " & Time
            Cells(x, 4).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
         End If
      Next
   End If
End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
   With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Gomb 3")
      .Top = Target.Offset(1).Top
      .Left = Target.Offset(, 1).Left
   End With
End Sub

Sub PrintScreen()
   ActiveSheet.PrintOut Copies:=2, Collate:=True
End Sub
```

Can you please help me to complete the task as described above?

Comment: We don't write your project for you here.  If you want help then you need to describe exactly what "I am stuck" means - what specific part of your task is giving you problems/  What code did you writer, and what happened (or didn't happen) when you ran it?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Tim. Yesterday I allocated my morning for development and completed the task. the only difference is I replaced the automation when reaching the 10th rows for a manual button (can't find solution for automation when completing the 10th row with data). if you could help me in that what function or sub can solve that, I would implement that also.

Answer (score 0):

See below - not heavily commented but ask if there's anything you can't figure out.

```vb
Option Explicit
Const NUM_COLS As Long = 4     'how many data columns
Const MAX_ROWS As Long = 10
Const RW_START As Long = 2     'first row of scans starts here
Const COL_QUANT As Long = 3    'quantity col
Const COL_TMSTMP As Long = 4   'timestamp column

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    If Target.Column = COL_QUANT And Target.Row >= RW_START Then
        With Target.EntireRow
            If Len(.Cells(COL_QUANT).Value) > 0 And _
               Len(.Cells(COL_TMSTMP).Value) = 0 Then
                TimeStamp .Cells(COL_TMSTMP)
            End If
        End With
    End If
    'filled max number of rows?
    If Application.CountA(Me.Cells(RW_START, COL_TMSTMP).Resize(MAX_ROWS)) = MAX_ROWS Then
        SavePrintClear
    End If
End Sub
'add a timestamp to a cell
Sub TimeStamp(c As Range)
    With c
        .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
        .Value = Now
    End With
End Sub

Sub SavePrintClear()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add()
    With Me.Range("A1").Resize(MAX_ROWS + 1, NUM_COLS) 'include headers
        .Copy wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
        '.PrintOut Copies:=2, Collate:=True
       .Offset(1, 0).ClearContents
    End With
    wb.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Saved\Scans_" & _
               Format(Now, "yyyymmdd_hhmmss") & ".xlsx"
    wb.Close False
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
   With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Gomb 3")
      .Top = Target.Offset(1).Top
      .Left = Target.Offset(, 1).Left
   End With
End Sub

Sub PrintScreen()
   ActiveSheet.PrintOut Copies:=2, Collate:=True
End Sub
```